# How to replace last 3 character with x from string in php?

Tags: php

```
$string = "Hello world country";  
echo substr($string, 0, -3).'xxx';
```

Actual output:

```
Hello world counxxx
```

Expected output:

```
Hexxx woxxx counxxx
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string first and apply to all strings in the resulting array (btw, your "unexpected" output wouldn't be unexpected if you read the manual on substr)

Comment: Very much depends on what your text can look like. Do you only want letters to be replaced, or should punctuation and/or numbers be replaced? What about words shorter than 3 letters?

Comment: See also [`str_word_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by @Alive to Die is great.

Another way is to use [`str_word_count()`](https://php.net/str_word_count) and [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) :

```
$string = "Hello world country";
$words = str_word_count($string, 1);
$words = array_map(function($word) {
     if (strlen($word) < 3) return $word;
     return substr($word, 0, -3) . 'xxx'; 
}, $words);
echo implode(' ', $words);
```

Output :

```
Hexxx woxxx counxxx
```

To mask the half of each words, you could use :

```
$string = "Hello world country";
$words = str_word_count($string, 1);
$words = array_map(function($word) {
     $half = floor(strlen($word)/2);
     return substr($word, 0, -$half) . str_repeat('x', $half); 
}, $words);
echo implode(' ', $words);
```

output :

```
Helxx worxx counxxx
```

Comment: If I want to show `x` half to string words for eg. `helxx worxx counxxx`. So, How can I do that?

Comment: You could use strlen/2, and `str_repeat` : [live demo](https://3v4l.org/Q0aEU)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `explode()`, `foreach()`, `implode()` and `substr()`

```
$string = "Hello world india";

$array = explode(' ',$string);

foreach($array as &$ar){
    
    $ar = substr($ar, 0, -3).'xxx';
}
echo implode(' ',$array);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/RhCA7

Note: My assumption here is words are separated with space and each word have letter count >= 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` and `substr`:

```
$string = "Hello world country"; 
$array = explode(' ',$string);
foreach($array as $ar){
    $ar = substr($ar,0,-3).'xxx';
    echo $ar." ";
}
```

Expected Output: `Hexxx woxxx counxxx`